# How to convert/import participants with partial payments

Tags: api, import

I've tried importing participants in the standard way, then importing contributions for their event deposits (partial payments), then using API CSV import to connect them via a ParticipantPayment import. However, things don't seem to behave correctly afterward.

Bringing the data directly in via SQL on civicrm_participants, civicrm_contributions, and civicrm_participant_payments doesn't seem to work either.

What is the correct way to convert in the data so these participants will be connected with their deposits?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the end, this can't be done with a simple import. We must populate all of the following tables:

- civicrm_participant
- civicrm_line_item
- civicrm_contribution
- civicrm_participant_payment
- civicrm_financial_item
- civicrm_financial_trxn
- civicrm_entity_financial_trxn

Given that complexity, I created a staging table and brought it all in via SQL scripts.